# Cascading Combobox in DataGrid using DataTemplate Cross-Cell Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

If I place my cascading comboboxes inside the same `DataTemplate` in a WPF `DataGrid` cell - the binding works properly (**via ElementName**). However, from a UI perspective I want my comboboxes to physically reside in different cells, not the same datagrid cell. How do you make cross-cell binding work (*between DataTemplates*) using `DataGridTemplateColumns`? It seems the issue is that the second comboboxes' `ItemsSource` cannot find the `ElementName` for binding when the comboboxes exist in different `DataTemplate` columns.

#### This works....

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdItems" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Model}">          
                <DataGrid.Columns>        
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Car Make / Model" Width="150">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="cbCarMake" SelectedItem="{Binding CarMake, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CarMakes, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID">
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                            <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.SelectCarMake}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </ComboBox>                            
                                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding CarModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbCarMake, Path=Tag.CarModels, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
```

#### This doesn't....

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="grdItems" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Model}">          
            <DataGrid.Columns>        
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Car Make" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cbCarMake" SelectedItem="{Binding CarMake, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CarMakes, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                            <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.SelectCarMake}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Car Model" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding CarModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbCarMake, Path=Tag.CarModels, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with cross-data template binding is to use the ViewModel as a go-between. When properties change on the view model (*an `ObservableCollection` in this case*), you can trigger this notification to the dependent listeners (*elements listening to PropertyChanged events*).

The issue for me was that the View Model wasn't receiving the `PropertyChanged` notifications it should have been. I assumed that the mvvm-light `ObservableObject` automatically triggered `PropertyChanged` events for all properties.

You must use the `mvvminpcset` code snippet which explicitly raises property change events for the items in your `ObservableCollection`. Once the PropertyChanged events started firing, the `ItemSource` binding worked as seen below.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdItems" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Model}">          
            <DataGrid.Columns>        
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Car Make" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cbCarMake" SelectedItem="{Binding CarMake, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CarMakes, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID">                                
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Car Model" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding CarModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding CarMake.CarModels}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```