# DataGrid binding in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, datatemplate

I'm currently trying to do some binding inside of a datagrid but I'm having problems getting up to the level of `DataContext` of the view.

Here is the code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Operators}"
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.OperatorList,ElementName=FilterGrid}" />
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Any ideas on whats wrong? The View's Viewmodel is connected in the code behind.

EDIT: The Binding that is not working is the `ItemsSource` binding shown above

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319662/how-do-i-bind-a-datagridcomboboxcolumn-to-entityframework-using-mvvm/9376563#9376563

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `DataTemplate` of the `DataGrid`, you cannot use `ElementName` bindings as it won't resolve properly due to limitations in the resolution capabilities of `FindControl` within the DataGrid control hierarchy. You need to use a `RelativeSource` binding that travels up the control tree looking for a specific control type (*which you need to determine - from your element name I assumed it was a `DataGrid` ancestor type*).

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <ComboBox 
        SelectedItem="{Binding Operators}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.OperatorList, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
      />
   </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728588/cascading-combobox-in-datagrid-using-datatemplate-cross-cell-binding) that shares some potentially related sample code using MVVM to access the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` host to populate a ComboBox `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and explaining why my code didn't work. Your solution did and you've been very helpful! Thanks!